# Spring Boot - No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot based web application which uses JPA and HSQLDB for data persistence, but now when I try to build my Project, it fails and says:

```
No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

My code is as follows:

Application

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

"Comentario" table

```
package dashboard.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="TComentarios")
public class Comentario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String contenido;
    @ManyToOne
    private Sugerencia sugerencia;
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fecha;

    Comentario(){}

    get/set...
}
```

Repository

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ComentarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Comentario, Long>{
@Query("select c from Comentario c where c.sugerencia = ?1")
List<Comentario> findBySugerencia(Sugerencia sugerencia);
}
```

pom.xml (dependencies part):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring Boot versions (1.4.4 and 1.5.2)...

Answer (score 0):

It will maybe not solve your problem but overriding the dependency version of artifact pulled by the spring-boot-starter-parent pom is not advised and may create side effects:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>    
 ....    
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It should be enough :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It is true for most of dependencies pulled by the starter pom but it is still more true for dependencies belonging to the `org.springframework.boot` groupId that are designed to work with the same version.

Comment: Sorry. As mentioned in the answer, it may not work but it is something to consider in your actual configuration.  You could have bad surprises because of it when your first problem will be solved. I have just tried to reproduce your problem but I have not it. Can you edit your question with all the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yes, but the strange part is that on Travis it doesn't fail, but on local yes